# Invalid input syntax when retrieving user data in e-commerce dashboard

Tags: node.js, passport.js, express-session

I'm trying to retrieve the user data and session when from the server (I'm using PostgreSQL). I have no idea how many changes I have already made...

Error:

`Server: "error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "NaN" Client: "Error: Error: Failed to fetch user data at fetchUserData", "GET (path...) 500 (Internal Server Error)"`

The problem is when I try to retrieve the user information from the back-end. It seems my response is always expecting a number and not working properly with the header

Index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

const swaggerUI = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');

const usersRoutes = require('./routes/usersRoutes');
const currentUserRoutes = require('./routes/currentUserRoutes');
const productsRoutes = require('./routes/productsRoutes');
const cartRoutes = require('./routes/cartRoutes');
const ordersRoutes = require('./routes/ordersRoutes');
const checkoutRoutes = require('./routes/checkoutRoutes');
const loginRouter = require('./routes/authRoute');

const client = require('./database/db');

app.use(express.json());

// Configure session middleware
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secretrestapi',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

// Initialize Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Configure session serialization and deserialization
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async function (id, done) {
  try {
    const { rows } = await client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id]);

    if (rows.length === 0) {
      return done(new Error('User not found'));
    }

    const user = rows[0]; // Assuming the result returns a single user
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);

    // The serialized user ID is stored now in the session and can be accessed through the req.session.passport.user property.
  }
});



// Enable CORS middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000'); // Set the allowed origin
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE'); // Set the allowed HTTP methods
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, credentials'); // Set the allowed headers
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); // Set to allow credentials (e.g., cookies)
  next();
});

// Route handlers and middlewares
app.use('/users', usersRoutes);
app.use('/users/current-user', currentUserRoutes);
app.use('/products', productsRoutes);
app.use('/cart', cartRoutes);
app.use('/orders', ordersRoutes);
app.use('/checkout', checkoutRoutes);
app.use('/users/login', loginRouter);

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerDocument));

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.json({ info: 'This is my E-commerce Rest API!' });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Dashboard.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import './dashboard.css';

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/users/current-user', {
          method: 'GET',
          credentials: 'include',
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to fetch user data');
        }

        const userDataResponse = await response.json();

        console.log('UserDataResponse:', userDataResponse);

        setUser(userDataResponse);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        setError(error.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, []);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    navigate('/users/login');
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className='dashboard'>
      <div className='dashboard-header'></div>
      <div className='dashboard-container'>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
        {user && (
          <div>
            <p>Welcome, {user.name}!</p>
          </div>
        )}
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to='/orders'>Orders</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/edit-info'>Edit Info</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/edit-address'>Edit Address</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

getCurrentUser function and route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const client = require('../database/db');

const getCurrentUser = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    const userId = req.session.passport.user;

    console.log('User ID:', userId);

    // Query the database to fetch the user data based on the user ID
    client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [userId], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Query Error:', error);
        return next(error);
      } else {
        const userData = results.rows[0]; // Assuming the user data is in the first row of the query results

        console.log('User Data:', userData);

        res.status(200).json(userData);
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'User not authenticated' });
  }
};

router.get('/', getCurrentUser);

module.exports = router;
```

After the user registering or login, I need to show his dashboard - Containing it's data and session. The session I will be using to integrate in all website (It's a e-commerce PERN project)

I've implemented the authenticate using passport and it's working fine. Also I made some logs after user login and I can see the session data, ID and the cookie in the console (server). But after that I got the error mentioned.

Thanks in advance for any help and please let me know if I need to show more code.